# Xpath - Select only parent node's text

Tags: xpath, web-crawler

I'm doing a little web crawling but I have some problems in selecting the right data to be extracted throught xpath statement. I hope someone here can give me the right solution so I can complete the job.
Here is the html of the site:

```
<h5><a href="some-website-url" target="_blank"> Some sample text</a> (2015)</h5>
```

I want to find a way to extract the text "(2015)" out of the site by give it an xpath statement but I could not figure it out. I tried

```
//HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/H5[1]/text()
```

but not success.

```
//HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/H5[1]
```

is what xpath address the program gave me when it extracted the text

```
Some sample text (2015)
```

out of the site.
And the code

```
//HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/H5[1]/text()
```

gave the same result.

Please help me a bit.

Thank you very much.

PS: The program I'm working on to extract the site is Octoparse version 6.2

Answer (score 0):

> to find a way to extract the text "`(2015)`"

**xpath** expression:

```
//div[1]/h5/a/following-sibling::text()
```

Comment: @Americanmylove, that's because you have posted a shortened input, post the actual input